# An Inverse Cosine Problem

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Here is my problem:

$$ \sin(\cos^{-1} \frac{2}{5} )  $$

I know how to do it for the most part; I just draw a triangle with sides *2*,*5* and *√21* and I then find the sine (opposite/hypotenuse) of the angle whose cosine is 2/5. The answer is **√21/5**. But is there a simpler way to tackle this problem that doesn`t involve as much work? Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Am I reading the problem correctly as $\sin \left( \cos^{-1} \left( 2/5 \right) \right)$? Also, your approach seems pretty simple as it is; I don't know how much simplification you'll find :)

Comment: Another approach would be to use $ \ \sin x \ = \ \pm \sqrt{1 \ - \ \cos^2 x } \ $ .  You know the angle concerned is in the first quadrant because the inverse cosine of a positive value gives such an angle.  Therefore the sine value will also be positive, and you can calculate $ \ +\sqrt{1 \ - \ (\frac{2}{5})^2  } \ $ .   It is up to you to decide if that is less work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. In general we take $y = \cos^{-1}{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)}$ or $\cos y = \frac{2}{5}$ so $\sin y = \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}$